# Maximum String Mismatches in Java

Tags: java, string

I was recently going through a question in codehub and I was unable to solve this query. Can anyone help me how can this be solved?

You are given a string S of length N. You can select and reverse any substring of S of any length. You are allowed to perform this operation many number of times.

Determine maximum number of mismatches by performing operation.

Mismatch(S) is defined as number of corresponding positions were characters are different in S and reverse(S). For example : S = abab, reverse(S) = baba. Number of mismatches = 4. S= abca. Number of mismatches = 2.

Pseudo code :

```
static int solve( String S, int n)
{
//To do
}
```

Will be helpful if some one can explain once the code is done how this can be interpreted more easily and approached to solve.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Not a homework. It was a competitive test for which i did not understand how to resolve it yet.

Comment: The process is called decomposition.  You take a problem statement, like the one given to you, and break it down into smaller problems, until you're confident you can code a solution to each of the smaller problems.  In the statement you provided, the intermediate steps are; 1) Reverse the String.  2) Compare the string and the reverse string, character by character, and count the differences.  Most experienced developers can decompose a problem statement like this in their head because they've coded similar methods before.

Comment: Very well explained Gilbert Le Blanc..!!

Comment: @MOnkey:  Thanks.  To the OP, because I ran out of room, Abhishek Kulkarni's answer is my decomposition, as well as his decomposition, in Java code.

Comment: @AnkitRajPrasad I also want to practice this Qn, I couldn't find any links. May you please share link to this Qn

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Here you could first reverse the giving string and then just iterate through the giving string and compare character at each index in both the giving string and reversed string and if there is a mismatch increase the counter.

Check the below code

```
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {

    String s = "abab";
    System.out.println(solve(s,s.length()));
}

static int solve( String s, int n)
{   
    //this can also be used to reverse string
    //String reversed = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();

    String revStr = Stream.of(s)
            .map(word->new StringBuilder(word).reverse())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    int counter = 0;
    for(int loop=0; loop < n; loop++){
        if(s.charAt(loop)!=revStr.charAt(loop)){
            ++counter;  
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: This is a wrong solution. This assumes, that the substring of the string can't be reversed. See the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/63753644/3904327

Answer (score 6):

I recently encountered the same question in one of the competency tests, I don't know about above solution, but my implementation below in python works for above problem

```
import itertools
def maximum_mismatches(s,n):
    if len(set(s)) == 1:
        return 0
    maxc = 0
    for str_c in set(itertools.permutations(s,n)):
        rev_str = str_c[::-1]
        counter = 0
        for i in range(n):
            if str_c[i] != rev_str[i]:
                counter += 1
        if maxc < counter:
            maxc = counter
    return maxc
```

I have tested for multiple test cases, it is working

Comment: I also want to practice this Qn, I couldn't find any links. May you please share link to this Qn

Comment: @ASharma7 there is no link as such, should have been added as a problem in any of the coding platforms now

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the frequency of each character in the string and then take the difference of frequency of each character. See the code example in **Java**. It returns the max mismatch of characters of a string & it's reverse, given that a substring in the original string can be reversed any number of times.

**Examples**: 1. cantaaaa (answer = 6), 2. cbbaa (answer = 4), 3. aaaaabbbbccdd (answer = 12)

```
public static int maxMismatch(String str){
    if(str == null || str.length() <= 1) return 0;

    int freq[] = new int[26];

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        freq[str.charAt(i) - 97]++;
    }

    int diff = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++){
        diff = Math.abs(freq[i] - diff);
    }

    return str.length() - diff;
}
```

Comment: I also want to practice this Qn, I couldn't find any links. May you please share link to this Qn

Comment: Unfortunately, a frequency-based approach gives the wrong answer. cantaaaa should give the answer 8 because the reverse aaaatnac has no common characters in corresponding positions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it
def mismatch(S,n):
    max =0
    for x in set(it.permutations(S[::-1],n)):
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(n):
            if x[i]!=S[i]:
                cnt+=1
        if cnt > max:
            max=cnt
    return max
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int max_mismatch(string s)
{
  unordered_map<char,int> fmap;
  for(auto &ch:s)
    fmap[ch]++;
  vector<int> tempV;
  for(auto &[_,f]:fmap)
     tempV.push_back(f);
  sort(tempV.begin(),tempV.end(),greater<int>());    
  vector<int> freq(tempV.size());
  int diff=0,left=0,right=freq.size()-1;
  bool leftinsert=true;
  for(auto f:tempV)
  {
      if(leftinsert)
          freq[left++]=f;
      else
         freq[right--]=f;
      leftinsert^=1;     
  }
  /*for(auto &val:freq)
     cout<<val<<" ";
  cout<<endl;  */
  left=0;right=freq.size()-1;
  for(int i=0;i<s.size()/2;i++)
  {
     if(left==right)
       break;
     if(!(--freq[left])) left++;
     if(!(--freq[right])) right--;
     diff+=2;
  }
  return diff;        
}
int main()
{
    string s="aatacanaa";
    cout<<max_mismatch(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First a function to calculate the mismatch score, using this spec:

> Mismatch(S) is defined as number of corresponding positions were characters are different in S and reverse(S). For example : S = abab, reverse(S) = baba. Number of mismatches = 4. S= abca. Number of mismatches = 2.

We don't need to actually reverse the string. Just compare the first character with the last, then the second with the second last, etc. I find it straightforward to use two index variables for something like this:

```
int mismatches(String s) {
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length() - 1;
    while (j >= 0) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(j)) result++;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here are some tests to increase our confidence:

```
@Test
public void test_mismatches() {
    assertEquals(0, mismatches(""));
    assertEquals(0, mismatches("a"));
    assertEquals(0, mismatches("aa"));
    assertEquals(2, mismatches("ab"));
    assertEquals(0, mismatches("aaa"));
    assertEquals(2, mismatches("aab"));
    assertEquals(2, mismatches("abc"));
    assertEquals(0, mismatches("aaaa"));
    assertEquals(2, mismatches("aaab"));
    assertEquals(2, mismatches("aaba"));
    assertEquals(4, mismatches("abcd"));
}
```

Now let's find the max mismatch. Here is the spec:

> You are given a string S of length N. You can select and reverse any
> substring of S of any length. You are allowed to perform this
> operation many number of times.
>
> Determine maximum number of mismatches by performing operation.

This is unclear and has typos. It is lazily written and if it was client work, I would be asking for a clarification. I've been burned in the past by working from unclear specs, and building something that the client didn't intend.

I think the use of the word "reverse" is a misnomer. I think it is to help hint at a solution for calculating the mismatch. The spec should be:

> You are given a string. Determine maximum number of mismatches from any substring. For clarity, the original string is a valid substring of itself.

With this revised spec, we can just use a nested for loop to traverse the search space:

```
int maxMismatches(String s) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        for (int j = s.length(); j > i; j--) {
            int mismatch = mismatches(s.substring(i, j));
            if (mismatch > result)
                result = mismatch;
        }
    return result;
}
```

And some tests:

```
@Test
public void test_max_mismatches() {
    assertEquals(0, maxMismatches(""));
    assertEquals(0, maxMismatches("a"));
    assertEquals(0, maxMismatches("aa"));
    assertEquals(2, maxMismatches("ab"));
    assertEquals(2, maxMismatches("aba"));
    assertEquals(4, maxMismatches("aabbaa"));
    assertEquals(6, maxMismatches("aaabcda"));
}
```

There is a gap in this set of tests. Some of the test strings require truncating the start to find the max. Some require truncating the end, but none require truncating both the start and end.

Both functions have obvious optimisations but they reduce clarity in a scenario where I don't think performance is important.

Comment: This is clearly a homework question. My answer tries to: show how I break the solution down, explains the sorts of algorithms that can be used for this problem and other similar problems, teach how I deal with unclear specs in my client work, show how simple it can be to write test code, champions clarity in production code, and warns against premature optimisation.