# In Java, how to restrict a user to enter only one type?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, while-loop, integer

In this case, I have asked the user to enter 1,2 or 3. If user enters string, it should ask the question again. when my code runs, every if statement is running, where as I want to run a specific if statement. It would be a huge favor if anyone could help me.

```
    String question = "What is the color of banana? Write 1,2 or 3. Choose one of the following:";
    String answerOne = "1. yellow";
    String answerTwo = "2. red";
    String answerThree = "3. blue";

    while(true){
        System.out.println(question + "\n" + answerOne + "\n" + answerTwo + "\n" + answerThree);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (input.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Please select a NUMBER between 1 and 3.");
        }
        if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Please select a NUMBER between 1 and 3.");
        }
        if (input.hasNextInt()) {
            int x = input.nextInt();
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations!! your answer is correct");
                break;
            }
            if (x == 2 || x == 3) {
                System.out.println("Sorry!! the correct answer is" + answerOne);
                break;
            }
            if (x > 3) {
                System.out.println("Please choose the correct answer!!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first that's not how `.hasSomething()` works, it used to check if there have more elements. So what you should do, is to read the input as a string and check that string:

```
 String question = "What is the color of banana? Write 1,2 or 3. Choose one of the following:";
        String answerOne = "1. yellow";
        String answerTwo = "2. red";
        String answerThree = "3. blue";

            System.out.println(question + "\n" + answerOne + "\n" + answerTwo + "\n" + answerThree);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            String c = input.next();//read the input
            
            while(!(c.charAt(0) >= '1' && c.charAt(0) <= '3') || c.length() != 1){ //check if it's a number between 1 and 3
                System.out.println("Enter agin:");
                c = input.next();
            }
            

            int x = Integer.parseInt(c);//change c to an integer
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations!! your answer is correct");
                break;
            }
            if (x == 2 || x == 3) {
                System.out.println("Sorry!! the correct answer is" + answerOne);
            }
```

Comment: Hi lier, please check this qn https://stackoverflow.com/q/60680525/4860775. I dont understand how this solution works https://stackoverflow.com/a/63753644/4860775

Comment: @ASharma7 Have you read the comment?"This is a wrong solution. This assumes, that the substring of the string can't be reversed. See the answer below stackoverflow.com/a/63753644/3904327 – Ashutosh Chamoli "

Comment: I prefer this approach, but I think you have one more loop than strictly necessary.  If the input is invalid you could just continue the outer loop.  Probably a matter of taste though.

Comment: @user14644949 True, I could just delete the outer loop

Comment: @ASharma7 ```revStr``` is just the reverse of the string you're given, then it loops through the string to check each position.

Comment: @lierwu yes i was also referring to the same solution of ashutosh chamoli. I think I made some mistake while copying url of Ashutosh

Comment: @lierwu i donot understand how only subtracting the frequencies of alphabets gave us the number of mismatches :(

Comment: @ASharma7 Ask him, I had no idea too...  QAQ :(

Comment: @ASharma7 I spend some time on it and find out that the solution was wrong, when you enter "abca", which should produce an answer of two, that guy's program produces an answer of 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problems are as follows.

1. You create a new scanner each time around the loop
2. Immediately after the new scanner is created, you execute a couple of 'hasNext' tests.  Nothing will have been typed.  You're possibly going to spin in that loop forever.
3. An integer is also a  double, so even if the user has typed an integer, it'll satisfy the 'if double' condition.
4. If an integer is not typed, the input is never read, so you're stuck at that point in the input stream.  You'll loop forever.

The flow should look like this:

```
input = new Scanner();
while (true) {
    print question...

    try {
        int x = input.nextInt(); // waits for user input
        process as before;
        if (correct answer) {
           break out of loop;
        }
        else {
           print "nope";
        }
     }
     catch (InputMismatchException ex) { // something that is not an integer
          print "type an integer";
          input.nextLine(); // skip incorrect input
     }
}
```

This is just a pseudocode sketch, of course.

It uses exception handling as the most convenient way to make sure an integer is input.  By calling nextInt() on the scanner, we assume the user is going to type something that is convertible to integer.  The try/catch structure handles the error case.

There are other ways to write this; my own inclination would be to read a line and parse it.  But this is closest to what I think was the original intent.

Comment: What is ```input.hasNextInt()```? Do you mean ```checkInputIsInteger```?_?

Comment: I mean the [hasNextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) method of the Scanner class, exactly as used by the OP in their original code.   Though I now see my answer repeated the flaw of the OP in not waiting for input. I'll fix that.

Comment: But you are not allowing the scanner to read any inputs. It's not going to wait... So it's going to return false the whole time QAQ

Comment: Yes, you are correct there. Will fix. Thanks.